How to implement and test RoPE Embeddings in Triton?
From the RoFormer paper, the RoPE embeddings was introduced.
https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.09864

And the formulation is 
If we were to code it in Triton, is this the right implementation for RoPe embeddings?
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import triton
import triton.language as tl

# 1. Rotary Positional Embeddings (RoPE)
@triton.jit
def rope_kernel(x_ptr, max_len, dim, stride, **meta):
    batch_size = tl.program_id(0)
    seq_len = tl.program_id(1)

    # Load the input tensor
    x = tl.load(x_ptr + (batch_size * stride) + (seq_len * dim))

    # Precompute frequency terms
    freq_indices = tl.arange(0, dim // 2)
    freqs = tl.arange(0, max_len)[:, None] * (1.0 / (10000 ** (freq_indices / dim)))

    # Compute sine and cosine for RoPE
    sin_freqs = tl.sin(freqs)
    cos_freqs = tl.cos(freqs)

    # Efficiently apply RoPE to the input
    for i in range(0, dim, 2):
        x_i = x[i:i+2]  # Load two elements at once
        x[i] = x_i[0] * cos_freqs[seq_len] - x_i[1] * sin_freqs[seq_len]
        x[i+1] = x_i[0] * sin_freqs[seq_len] + x_i[1] * cos_freqs[seq_len]

    # Store the output
    tl.store(x_ptr + (batch_size * stride) + (seq_len * dim), x)

How do I test to see if the triton kernels are working properly as per defined by the rope embeddings formulation?
